# Copy filtered column into another blank column, but keeping the row number using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to copy some filtered values from a column (using `isin` and a list with the values I want to filter), but I don't know how to copy those filtered values from that column and paste stick them into another blank column. I also need the values to keep their row number

I need help with this because I was doing research about this theme but I didn't find anything.

```
color_colors = ['Blanco negro rojo','Gris multicolor','Negro','Negro/Gris']

data_Color_colores = data[data['Color'].isin(color_colors)]
```

The code above is for the filtering part.  I really don't know how to copy the values that this code bring back, into my new blank column named: `"New_Color"`

Updates:
The below image is my dataframe. I have the three UNTIDY columns: Color, Size and Type. So, I want to filter in each of these three columns, by the information I provide in a list, then copy that information filtered and stick the values with their respective row number into the "New_Color" if that values are colors, into "New_Size" if that values is a size or into "New_type" if these values are Types.

[image]

To change this columns to untidy to tidy, I want to paste the respective values from these three columns into the new ones, but my my self filtering first the possible color values in column "Color", then filtering by possible Size values and stick them into new size column, then with possible Type values into "Color" again... AND THEN go to the next column which is "SIZE" and perform the literally the same actions that I perform in the previous column (color). So with this method, when I finish, the three columns (Color, size and Type) will be TIDY in the new ones (New_Color, New_Size, New_Type)

Comment: I do not understand. Would'nt `New_Color` just be the same as `Color` but NaN when it is not in your predefined vector?

Comment: The thing here is that i have three untidy columns, so i trying to tidy this columns into new ones. In this first case i'm trying to filter by the values color_colors, but in the same column there are number and other information that it wouldn't be there so, i'm filterin by these values first, trying to stick them into a new blan column and then, do the same thing with the other values in that COLOR column (untidy column).  Then, the next part of the task will be filter the other two columns that i didt mention before, because is the same logic

Comment: please provide some sample data

Comment: Yeah sure, gimme a second

Comment: @mnist i add some comments in the problem description , with pictures

Comment: To preserve row number you can make that colum as index, and then copy your filtered results to another DF , ignoring new index.

Comment: @LorenzoBassetti and how do i do that? sorry i'm a little  lost :/